# one to many - sequelize update - not removing/inserting children

Tags: one-to-many, sequelize.js

So I've been struggling for a few hours now with a one-to-many mapping update.

I've got a `project` which has certain `tasks` (for example).
I add and remove tasks through the frontend and send the revised object to by backend running with sequelize.

Then I tried to update the records as follows:

```
return models.Project
    .findOne({
        where: { id: projectToUpdate.id },
        include: [models.Task]
    })
    .then(function (ProjectFromDb) {
        return models.sequelize
            .transaction({
                isolationLevel: models.sequelize.Transaction.ISOLATION_LEVELS.READ_COMMITTED
            },
            function (t) {
                return ProjectFromDb
                    .update(projectToUpdate,
                    {
                        include: [{ model: models.Task }]
                    })
                });
    })
    .then(function (result) {
        return output.getSuccessResult(....
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        return output.getErrorResult(....
    });
```

But this would only update the `Project`

Next I tried to update them with an additional `then` call:

```
.then(function (updateResult) {
        return updateResult.setTasks(projectToUpdate.Tasks, {transaction: t})
    })
```

But this would give me the result that he is trying to update the `Task` and set the `ProjectId` to `NULL` which is not possible because it is non-nullable.

I am currently "manually" adding the `tasks` and removing them but this seems to be a silly way of using the framework.

Can anyone tell me how to properly make this work with a one-to-many relationship without me calling `Tasks.createBulk` and `Tasks.destroy`?

**EDIT TO INCLUDE MODEL**
JSON object looks like this:

```
{
    id: 1,
    projectName: 'nameOfTheProject',
    Tasks: [
        projectId: 1,
        name: 'taskName'
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the content of `projectToUpdate` at this point? Is it a sequelize model, or just an ordinary JS object? Thanks

Comment: It is a JSON object coming from the front-end. Nothing more. i.e. `{name: "somename", Tasks: [..sometasks..] }` (this is simplified of course)

Comment: Right, and what's the format of the objects in the `Tasks` list? Do they have an attribute `ProjectId`? Sorry for the abuse, but It would be nice if you could update your question with a legitimate JSON representation of your `projectToUpdate` at runtime

Comment: Editted my question and added a basic view of the model I send

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try changing the property name `projectId` to `ProjectId` on your `Tasks` objects that are nested to the `projectToUpdate` object.

---

**Update**

[Looking at sequelize's source](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/3e5b8772ef75169685fc96024366bca9958fee63/lib/instance.js#L697), it seems that the `Instance.$save()` function  (which is called by [`Instance.$update()`](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/3e5b8772ef75169685fc96024366bca9958fee63/lib/instance.js#L796) that you're using) does not support nested models creation when you're **updating** it - it checks if the flag `wasNewRecord` is `true` before doing it.

Comment: That makes no sense really, since my foreignkey is projectId (non capital). Anyway I tried and it did not work.

Comment: The tables were created by sequelize? Or you just mapped them? Because all the times I used sequelize the FK was created with TitleCase by default. 

Have you tried with the additional `then` call? 

`.then(function (updateResult) {
        return updateResult.setTasks(projectToUpdate.Tasks, {transaction: t})
    })`

Comment: in that case I get following error: `val.replace is not a function`

Comment: I believe the `setTasks` only tries to link the `id`'s, kind of like it does in a `many-to-many`. So if that is the case, I have no choice but to first create or delete them before matching said tasks, do I?

Comment: My mistake, I didn't realize that the tasks that you're trying to assign are not inserted in the DB yet.

[Here](http://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/associations/#creating-elements-of-a-hasmany-or-belongstomany-association) is the doc for creating nested models, but I see you already tried that. The difference is that you're trying to update the `Project` adding new `Tasks`, while the docs example is creating instances of both models..

However, one difference that I found is that your `Tasks` attribute at `projectToUpdate` is w/ capital `T`, while in the docs they are downcase.

Comment: Yes but this is probably because they use the "as" keyword to make them lowercase, with me - checking the object that's returned - the tasks are with capitals. If you update your answer explaining how this works exactly, I'll accept.

Comment: I took a look at sequelize's source and I think that I found why it's not working.. I updated my anwser explaining that.